# Sort object javascript

Tags: javascript

There are lots of questions similar to this but I couldn't find any quite like this. Here is my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < count_batters; i++) {
  var post = {
    player_name: jsonData[i].player_name,
    fantasy_points: jsonData[i].avg_fpts_fd
  }
  console.log(post);

  function compare(a,b) {
    if (a.fantasy_points < b.fantasy_points)
      return -1;
    if (a.fantasy_points > b.fantasy_points)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  post.sort(compare);
```

I want to sort "post" by "fantasy_points". It is sorted by player_name by default. I have tried .sort() which doesn't work on this object. The error the above code gives is `undefined is not a function`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sort? `post` is a single object, it doesn't make sense trying to sort it.

Comment: `undefined is not a function` that's because an object doesn't have a `sort` method (unless you give it one). An array does, but you don't have an array.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. SO post is always one object even though when the loop is finished there are over 300 lines? I am trying to sort the result of the loop.

Comment: What "result of loop"? You create an object and then `console.log` it. You don't do anything else with that object.

Comment: Bare with me.. Newbie here... but i think it's coming together... Should I push each iteration into an array and then "sort" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push the objects into an array, then you can sort the array:

```
var posts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < count_batters; i++) {
  var post = {
    player_name: jsonData[i].player_name,
    fantasy_points: jsonData[i].avg_fpts_fd
  };
  posts.push(post);
}

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.fantasy_points < b.fantasy_points)
    return -1;
  if (a.fantasy_points > b.fantasy_points)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

posts.sort(compare);
```

Answer (score -4):

Looks like your compare function is inside of the for loop? If you take it out I imagine it would work. Or you could just put an anonymous function in sort as your compare function

```
post.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.fantasy_points < b.fantasy_points)
    return -1;
  if (a.fantasy_points > b.fantasy_points)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```