# Trending topic algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var object = [
    {name: "christmas", mentions: 56, last_mention: 12},
    {name: "paris", mentions: 92, last_mention: 13},
    {name: "halloween", mentions: 64, last_mention: 34},
    {name:"easter", mentions: 124, last_mention: 213} 
]
```

Where `last_mention` is the amount of days ago that it was mentioned last.

I want to order the object so that the trends is being displayed first. For example, the story of Paris is trending now, so it should be at the top, although it isn't the latest. Easter should be at the bottom as it is old news. Is there an algorithm in JavaScript that I can use for this?

**My Final Solution**

```
var a = 4;
var b = 1;
object.sort(function(c, n){
    return (a * c.last_mention + b * c.mentions) > (a * n.last_mention + b * n.mentions);
});
```

Thanks to @crl from the chat.

Comment: No algorithm can [sort data inside an object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31817351/2564301).

Comment: @Jongware: That's no longer true. As of ES2015 (aka ES6), object properties have order. Granted, to sort an object's properties, you have to create a *new* object (thanks to IE). Not that it's the right solution to doing *this*, though. :-)

Comment: Ah - one of the foundations of an abstract `object` (as "container of arbitrary information") has been undermined by popular demand... Still, by far the easiest method would be to throw everyting into an array, as that is a far more logical way of storing this set of data.

Comment: @Jongware: The primary utility of it, really, is consistent serialization order. (That and *people kept assuming they had order*, and engines provided order but inconsistently, leading to traps for people to fall into.) It's not something you'd want to use for this kind of task.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: at least OP did not ask for a regex solution...

Comment: "I want to order the object". I think OP means sort the array named "object" based on some criteria, in which case I'd suggest reading about [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use your own sorting methods

```
function last_mention(a,b){
  return a.last_mention - b.last_mention;
}

function mentions(a,b){
  if(a.mentions === b.mentions)
    return a.last_mention - b.last_mention;
  return false;
}

var trendings= [
    {name: "christmas", mentions: 56, last_mention: 12},
    {name: "paris", mentions: 92, last_mention: 13},
    {name: "halloween", mentions: 64, last_mention: 34},
    {name:"easter", mentions: 124, last_mention: 213} 
];

trendings.sort(last_mention);
trendings.sort(mentions);
```

you can test yous out put

```
console.log(trendings);
```